# Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.6 - Compatibility

Tags: elasticsearch

I am wondering which version of Elasticsearch does Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.6 support?

Currently I am working with Elasticsearch 6.2, is this compatible?
Right now I am using the Elasticsearch Rest Client for Java, but since I am using Spring I thought about using Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [POM of the 3.0.6 release](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/be230f4003653ed2bb5268a3bd956ccbba60c420/pom.xml#L22), the supported version is 5.5.0